# Google Cloud Load balancer URL Rewrite not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to setup google cloud load-balancer with HTTPS proxy. The rewrite rules doesn't seem to work. I've attached a screenshot of the same. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Basically I'm trying to access `<domain>/api/ping` on `<domain>/ping`. Not sure what the `Host rewrite` is about as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried in a web browser 35.186.214.135/ping/ and gave me an error as you said. 35.186.214.135/api/ping works. Did you follow the [Rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite) how-to guide?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that (at the moment) GCP Load Balancers rewrite is only a "path prefix" rewrite, not a full rewrite, i.e. it prepends the value of the "path prefix rewrite" onto the original request URL.

So I suspect what you have currently is resulting in a request to `restoplus-api-backend-services` with a URL of `/api/ping/ping`.

If you set the value of "path prefix rewrite" to `/api`, you should get a request to your backend of `/api/ping`.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm serving my bucket from /files/public/ and I'm trying to rewrite so that I don't have to nest my files in the bucket under/files/public -- I've set the host prefix to just /* but hitting not-found, without the re-write, if I nest it in the appropriate folders, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for this. To avoid having Not Found message for static content, you need to update your bucket with `gsutil web set` to set the error_page parameter (-e) as your `index.html`:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e index.html gs://<bucket-name>
```

Found this here:
https://serverfault.com/a/1045214/172334

Answer (score -2):

You should change your path prefix rewrite from "/API/ping" to "/". It will be work If you use a bucket.