# Deploy SPA application on Google Cloud Storage using Load Balancer and CDN

Tags: reactjs, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I'm investigating a way of deploying an Angular or React web application on Google Cloud using GCS, Load Balancer, and CDN.

I've set up the LB and the GCS using the *urlRewrite*, but since the LB does not allow *full URL rewrite* only **pathPrefixRewrite**, I cannot redirect all the requests to `/index.html`

I want to achieve the same functionality as firebase hosting where you can specify the rewrite rules

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

Another option will be to set the 404 page as `index.html`, but that will result in a `404 status code` return by the server, which I don't like.

Is this possible with Load Balancer, because they are not supporting a full rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google added rewrite engine in 2020 (see https://serverfault.com/questions/927143/how-to-manage-url-rewrites-with-a-gcp-load-balancer/1045214) and it is only capable `pathPrefixRewrite` (stripping fixed prefix).

For SPA you need variable suffix rewrite to `index.html` so you use Nginx or Firebase.

Or mentioned error handler in bucket's HTTP server (with a downside of HTTP code 404 for your virtual URLs):

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e index.html gs://web-stage/
```

Full instructions to set SPA app is here: [Google cloud load balancer create backend service for Firebase Hosting to serve microservices & frontend SPA from the same domain via load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681941/google-cloud-load-balancer-create-backend-service-for-firebase-hosting-to-serve)

Discussion of LB rewrite engine limitations:

- [How can I implement a .htaccess configuration in Firebase Hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130632/how-can-i-implement-a-htaccess-configuration-in-firebase-hosting)
- [Google Cloud Load balancer URL Rewrite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113189/google-cloud-load-balancer-url-rewrite-not-working)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/8zgg20/static_website_url_rewrite/

Comment: The new load balancer supports now  [wildcards and pattern matching operators in path templates for route rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#wildcards-regx-dynamic-route) in preview.

Comment: @DavidSpiess Cool! Finally they did it )) Currently it is limited only to *a global external HTTP(S) load balancer*.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible with the global external load balancer routing rules to rewrite every cloud storage request to serve the index.html.

```yaml
defaultService: projects/xxxx/global/backendBuckets/dashboard
name: path-matcher-1
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - pathTemplateMatch: /**
  priority: 10
  service: projects/xxxx/global/backendBuckets/dashboard
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathTemplateRewrite: /index.html
```